# How do I tell if motherboard is sending video on hdmi

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard, hdmi

My motherboard B75M-D3H has VGA/DVI/hdmi output.

Monitor 1: dvi + vga
Monitor 2(Dell S2340L): hdmi + vga

Monitor 2 never shows any display when connected thru hdmi cable but it works fine thru vga.
This page http://www.gigabyte.us/products/prod...px?pid=4150#sp says:

```
Integrated Graphics Processor:
1 x D-Sub port
1 x DVI-D port, supporting a maximum resolution of 1920x1200. The DVI-D port does not support D-Sub connection by adapter.
1 x HDMI port, supporting a maximum resolution of 1920x1200
```

How do I tell if motherboard is sending data on hdmi at all? Or is there a problem with my monitor?

Does gigabyte B75M-D3H motherboard support hdmi and dvi output at the same time for a dual monitor setup?

Comment: Is there a way to find out from the OS - some commandline utility maybe - to find out if some data is being sent out on hdmi?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-b75m-d3h_e.pdf):

> *Dual Display Configurations for the Onboard Graphics:*
>   This motherboard provides three video output ports: D-Sub, DVI-D, and
>   HDMI. Dual monitor confgurations are supported in operating system
>   environment only, but not during the BIOS Setup or POST process.

They sell DVI-d to HDMI cables and adapters. If you were to use one of these to test with the on-board DVI port this might give you an indication as to whether it's the motherboard's port or the monitor's port, or the HDMI cable you're using.

On one of my monitors the HDMI cable almost has to "click" in before the screen will display properly. The connection was loose and in online forums people were complaining about the HDMI connections, but in actuality it was because of a recessed socket. This might be the case with yours as well.

Comment: Monitor 2 works if I connect its hdmi port to PC's DVI port using the cable you mentioned. So, it is either a bad hdmi-hdmi cable or bad hdmi port on the motherboard.

Comment: If you spin the cable around you can test the HDMI port with the DVI monitor.

Comment: Great idea! I disconnected cables from dvi/vga port on the mb and then connected the hdmi port of the motherboard with the dvi port on monitor 1. Rebooted. No display on monitor 1. I think the hdmi port on the monitor is not working properly. Thanks cpattersonv1. I could get the warranty replacement on the mb but it isn't bothering me that much.

Comment: Btw, you don't need reboot. If it works, it will be detected straight away. It may be turned off in setting though (Screen Resolution page of Control Panel in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check: in BIOS Setup of some motherboards, there is switch for DVI and HDMI connectors, as they can't be used simultaneously.

I've not found anything like that in manual of your motherboard though, but it may be outdated (for older BIOS version), so better check it yourself. It should be on Peripherals page of BIOS Setup (§2-6/page 35 of [manual](http://download.gigabyte.ru/manual/mb_manual_ga-b75m-d3h_e.pdf)). (hint: don't switch IDE/AHCI mode after installing OS, as OS will only boot in mode in was installed in).